# jQuery Chained Select Ajax - help needed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I recently posted my question [see previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223777/jquery-to-update-select-list-not-like-the-other-questions) and received a great working solution but when I applied the solution to my code, I found that if there was any html tags between the two selects, the second select list would not update.  My guess is that the .next was not finding the class I was searching for.

```
<cfloop query="rsRequestSystems">
<tr>
    <td><select class="platform" name="platform" id="platform">
            <option></option>
            <cfloop query="rsPlatform">
                <option value="#rsPlatform.optionValue#" <cfif rsRequestSystems.platform eq rsPlatform.optionValue>selected</cfif>>#rsPlatform.optionDesc#</option>
            </cfloop>
        </select></td>
    <td><select name="model" id="model">
            <option></option>
            <cfloop query="rsModels">
                <option value="#rsModels.optionValue#" <cfif rsRequestSystems.model eq rsModels.optionValue>selected</cfif>>#rsModels.optionDesc#</option>
            </cfloop>
        </select></td>
</tr>
```

and the jQuery code is:

```
$(".platform").live("change", function() {
    var firstOption = $(this);
    $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels",{platform: $(this).val()},      
    function(j){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
            {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
    firstOption.next("#model").html(options);
    });
});
```

and here is a sample of the json data being returned:

```
[{"optionValue":"", "optionDisplay":"Select Model"},]
```

Comment: I should add that rows can be dynamically added and therefore I cannot rely on unique IDs.  The idea is that the user will populate the form by adding the necessary systems and then submit one large form.  It is not the preferred way to do this, I know, but I'm working with requirements.  There could easily be 100+ systems and the client doesn't want the end user to have to wait for the page to refresh as the systems are added before the final submit.

Comment: I cannot rely on unique ID's, unfortunately.  If I were to verbally walk through this, I would say, "When the .platform changes, I need to find the parent table containing the select.platform that was changed, and then update the select.models with the results from the ajax call."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs have to be **unique**. As your code represents a table row, I assume other rows look similar. If this is the case, use classes instead.
But if these are really the only elements with this IDs you can simply use:

```
$('#model').html(options);
```

---

`next` only selects the next sibling if it matches the selector. Based on your HTML, you could do:

```
firstOption.parent().next().children('select').html(options);
```

---

Actually, your code should not work as you add the `live` handler to elements with **class** `platform`, not ID. Maybe a typo?

Assuming your elements have *classes* instead of IDs, you can also do:

```
firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html(options);
```

Comment: It represents a table row, yes, but actually it is a snippet from a table that is actually looping and not just the row alone.  There are 10 other fields I left out for simpler code to post here.

Comment: @dlackey: Of course. I'm just saying that I assume from that, that the other rows also contain elements with the same IDs. You should use classes instead.

Comment: this option worked.  `firstOption.closest('tr').find('.model').html(options);`
I'll add this to my "prod" code to see if it works there.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

why not just this:

```
$("#model").html(options);
```

the `<select>` already has an id assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
$(".platform").live("change", function() {
    var firstOption = $(this);
    $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels",{platform: $(this).val()},      
    function(j){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
            {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
   $("#model").html(options);
    });
});
```

Just change the next, I think because is an ID, there wouldn't be another element with the same ID.